# ASP.NET MVC 5 foreign key nullable isn't working

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In the code below you see "Product" and "Supplier". In Product "SupplierID" is not required. But if I start my application and I want to add a new product, I am unable to set it be null. 
I've already tried to change the model into "public int? SupplierID { get; set; }". This isn't working :( In the database is SupplierID nullable. Please help.

```
 public class Product
 {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Artikelnummer is verplicht")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Artikel nummer")]
    public string ArticleNr { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam is verplicht")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Productnaam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Kleur")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Lengte")]
    public string Length { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Beschrijving is verplicht")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Beschrijving")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Afbeelding")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Inventory> Inventorys { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Projectnaam is verplicht")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Projectnaam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Projectleider is verplicht")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Projectleider")]
    public string ProjectLeader { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefoonnummer is verplicht")]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Voer een geldig telefoonnummer in")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Telefoonnummer")]
    public string PhoneNr { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is verplicht")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Voer een geldig e-mail in")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Define "isn't working".

Comment: You've got conflicting statements "In Product 'SupplierID' is not required." and "I can't let it be null". Which is it? `int?` is the technique for making a FK nullable. It should make a nullable field in the database.

Comment: I want to make the FK nullable. So a Product can have a Supplier or not (null).
If I change "public int SupplierID { get; set; }" in Product into "public int? SupplierID { get; set; }", it stil won't work.

Comment: How are you setting `SupplierID` when you make it `int?SupplierID`

Comment: If it is optional, then the SupplierID property must be int?. What are you using for mapping? (Assuming this is EF based on the tag) Code first or EntityTypeConfiguration?  Also, in the case where you are expecting to save a product with a null Supplier ID, you're certain you *are not* assigning a Supplier reference to that Supplier property, correct?

Comment: @Steve Py - I use "code first". And I think I'm not assigning a reference. I'm a little new with ASP.NET MVC ;) Do you need some code?

Comment: Its finally working :D